# jaGrid Master Detail Works Once

Tags: jqgrid, master-detail

There are two grid at my page. When a row is clicked at first grid data loads to another grid. When I click any of row at first time it works well. However it doesn't work at second click. This is my function:

```
onSelectRow: function (deviceGroupId) {
    $("#" + deviceGridId).jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        url: deviceGroupUrl + '/' + deviceGroupId
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't posted the grid definition which is very important to understand your problem. So I try to guess. I suppose, that you use `loadonce: true` in the second (detail) grid. The option will be used in combination with `datatype: 'json'` or `datatype: 'xml'`. After the first load the `datatype` will be changed to 'local'. As the result the local sorting and local paging of data will be used. On every sorting for example the grid will be reloaded, but with the *local* data.

If you need to reload the data having `loadonce: true` option once more time from the server you have to change `datatype` parameter to its original value, like `datatype: 'json'`:

```
onSelectRow: function (deviceGroupId) {
    $("#" + deviceGridId).jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        url: deviceGroupUrl + '/' + encodeURIComponent(deviceGroupId),
        datatype: 'json'
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set that:

```
loadonce: false
```

and it works.

Comment: You should always post definition of the grid which you have. The usage of `loadonce: false` or just removing of `loadonce: false` means  that the server sorted the data corresponds to `sidx` and `sord` and that the data paging sill be also implemented on the server side corresponds to `page` and `rows` parameters. Do the server this in your case?

Comment: Your answer explains the situation thanks. I don't make server side paging processing but I will try to implement it. Thanks.